# Semantic UI Transition not working in Meteor 1.3+

Tags: jquery, meteor, semantic-ui

I recently upgraded to Meteor 1.3.2.4, and all of the Javascript behaviors seem to be broken. For instance, I have a dismissable message block with this HTML:

```
<div class="ui error message">
    <i class="close icon"></i>
    <div class="header">
        Your manual overrides are extremely limited in duration!
    </div>
    <span class="reason">You're wasting your time, Captain.</span>
</div>
```

And this javascript:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { $ } from 'meteor/jquery';
import { FlowRouter } from 'meteor/kadira:flow-router';

import '../../../client/lib/semantic-ui/definitions/modules/transition';

import './login.html';

Template.App_login.events({
  'submit #login-form'(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       const user = event.target.user.value;
       const password = event.target.password.value;

       Meteor.loginWithPassword(user, password, (error) => {
           if (error) {
               $('.error.message').toggleClass('hidden')
                  .find('.reason').text(error.reason);
           } else {
               FlowRouter.go('App.home');
           }
      });
  },
  'click .close.icon'(event) {
      $(event.target).closest('.message').transition('fade');
  },
});
```

When I click on the close icon I receive the error `Transition: Element is no longer attached to DOM. Unable to animate. fade <div class=​"ui error message">​…​</div>​`

This is also happening with `popup`.

This seems similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36341989/semantic-ui-behaviors-not-working-in-meteor-1-3), which is still waiting for an accepted answer.

Project Branch: https://github.com/blueknightone/2-minute-attack/tree/2-minute-attack-11

Comment: Did you import semantic ui on your js file.

Comment: I'm using the `semantic:ui` package, which is supposed to work without importing. But yes, I have tried importing both transition.js and transition.import.less

I will update my post with the imports.

Comment: I think the real problem is while importing. Best thing you can do that check that in console(browser). You can also use this package https://atmospherejs.com/semantic/ui-transition. let me know if is not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Pankaj Jatav's suggestion above, I looked closer at imports, but not in the JS file.

It turns out that the problem is due to Semantic-UI's theming mechanism. I am using the Material theme, and had switched everything in `themes.config.import.less` to `'material`.

**The fix turned out to be to reset `@transition : 'material';` to `@transition : 'default';` in `client/lib/semantic-ui/themes.config.import.less`**

That fixed the problem with both transition and popup. And since I have the `semantic:ui` package, importing or using packages like `semantic:ui-transition` are not needed.

Thanks Pankaj for getting me on the track I needed to go on.